# Removing all characters before and after text in R, then creating columns from the new text

Tags: r

So I have a string that I'm attempting to parse through and then create 3 columns with the data I extract. From what I've seen, stringr doesn't really cover this case and the gsub I've used so far is excessive and involves me making multiple columns, parsing from those new columns, and then removing them and that seems really inefficient.

The format is this:

`"blah, grabbed by ???-??-?????."`

I need this:

`???-??-?????`

I've used placeholders here, but this is how the string typically looks

`"blah, grabbed by PHI-80-J.Matthews."`

or

`"blah, grabbed by NE-5-J.Mills."`

and sometimes there is text after the name like this:

`"blah, grabbed by KC-10-T.Hill. Blah blah blah."`

This is what I would like the end result to be:

| Place | Number | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PHI | 80 | J.Matthews |
| NE | 5 | J.Mills |
| KC | 10 | T. Hill |

Edit for further explanation:

Most strings include other people in the same format so `"downed by"` needs to be incorporated in someway to make sure it is grabbing the right name.

Ex.

`"Throw by OAK-4-D.Carr, snap by PHI-62-J.Kelce, grabbed by KC-10-T.Hill. Penalty on OAK-4-D.Carr"`

Desired Output:

| Place | Number | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KC | 10 | T. Hill |

Comment: Are you going to change again

Comment: Sorry that is it, wanted to be as thorough and clear as possible.

Comment: updated thepopst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution simply `extract` the components based on the logic OP mentioned i.e. capture the characters that are needed as three groups - 1) one or more upper case letter (`[A-Z]+`) followed by a dash (`-`), 2) then one or more digits (`\\d+`), and finally 3) non-whitespace characters (`\\S+`) that follow the dash

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, col1, into = c("Place", "Number", "Name"), 
      ".*grabbed by\\s([A-Z]+)-(\\d+)-(\\S+)\\..*", convert = TRUE)
```

-ouputt

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Place Number Name      
  <chr>  <int> <chr>     
1 PHI       80 J.Matthews
2 NE         5 J.Mills   
3 KC        10 T.Hill    
4 KC        10 T.Hill
```

---

Or do this in `base R`

```
read.table(text = sub(".*grabbed by\\s((\\w+-){2}\\S+)\\..*", "\\1", 
    df1$col1), header = FALSE, col.names = c("Place", "Number", "Name"), sep='-')
  Place Number       Name
1   PHI     80 J.Matthews
2    NE      5    J.Mills
3    KC     10     T.Hill
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("blah, grabbed by PHI-80-J.Matthews.", 
"blah, grabbed by NE-5-J.Mills.", "blah, grabbed by KC-10-T.Hill. Blah blah blah.", 
"Throw by OAK-4-D.Carr, snap by PHI-62-J.Kelce, grabbed by KC-10-T.Hill. Penalty on OAK-4-D.Carr"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate the ```grabbed by``` part to this? Sometimes there are other names in these strings in the exact same format and that throws this off.

Comment: @Loons22 what all other formats you have and what would be the expected output for those cases

Comment: Edited my original question to further explain.

Answer (score 2):

This solution actually does what you say in the title, namely first remove the text around the the target substring, then split it into columns:

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(col1 = str_extract(col1, "\\w+-\\w+-\\w\\.\\w+")) %>%
  separate(col1, 
           into = c("Place", "Number", "Name"), 
           sep = "-")
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Place Number Name      
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>     
1 PHI   80     J.Matthews
2 NE    5      J.Mills   
3 KC    10     T.Hill
```

Here, we make use of the fact that the character class `\\w` is for letters irrespective of case and for digits (and also for the underscore).

Comment: Would there be a way to incorporate the ```"downed by"``` portion into this? Sometimes there are other names in these strings and that throws this off.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example of those `downed by`portions that you would like to be included? Inlduded where - in another column? You need to be more specific...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way using `sub` with regex `"([A-Za-z]+\\.[A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1"` that removes the string after the second point.
`separate` that splits the string by `by`, and finally again `separate` to get the desired columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
    mutate(test1 = sub("([A-Za-z]+\\.[A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", col1)) %>% 
    separate(test1, c('remove', 'keep'), sep = " by ") %>% 
    separate(keep, c("Place", "Number", "Name"), sep = "-") %>% 
    select(Place, Number, Name)
```

Output:

```
  Place Number Name      
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>     
1 PHI   80     J.Matthews
2 NE    5      J.Mills   
3 KC    10     T.Hill
```